# Error when using Spatial Index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geospatial, spatial-index

I use Spatial Index and when I try to execute `WHERE` statement:

```
WHERE T.GEOMETRY.STIntersects(O.GEOMETRY) = 1 AND T.GEOMETRY.STTouches(O.GEOMETRY) = 0
```

It works fine, but when I try to execute with OR:

```
WHERE T.GEOMETRY.STOverlaps(O.GEOMETRY) = 1 OR T.GEOMETRY.STWithin(O.GEOMETRY) = 1
```

I get this error:

> The query processor could not produce a query plan for a query with a
>   spatial index hint.  Reason: Could not find required binary spatial
>   method in a condition.  Try removing the index hints or removing SET
>   FORCEPLAN.

Any help, what is a problem in this statement?

Comment: So, the error message alludes to a spatial index hint. Are you trying to force the optimizer's hand by doing something like "from tbl with (index(idx_spatial))"?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using "FROM Table WITH (INDEX (spatial_index))". I don't understand this error, why does it work with AND but not with OR.

Comment: I don't know, but the server is obviously angry at your attempts to circumvent what it would normally do. Ditch the index hint: they're typically reserved for when you really know what you're doing (not saying you're a rookie, but it's rare that anyone is smarter than the optimizer).

Comment: similar? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911473/using-stcrosses-with-a-spatial-index-in-sql-server

Comment: No, this is different error: "Could not find required binary spatial method in a condition"

Comment: Check on this MSDN post, a similar issue was found and it turned out to be the compatibility level of the database: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlspatial/thread/06c5076a-b41d-4bf1-9dd0-0ce65c5b307a

Comment: Do you have the complete query? You say you are using an index hint? Have you tried to execute the query without the hint?

Comment: I had something similar.  Best I could figure is the And allowed for a linear type execution plan and the Or did not.  I did not say it was an answer - said the best I could figure.

Comment: Doesn't "within" imply "overlap"?

Answer (score 1):

A general solution for issues with OR queries ( typically performance) is to separate them and use UNION ALL between then. This would typically be done in a sub-query, or a Common table expression.

If you could post more of your query, and preferably the relevant table schema, then I can update my answer with a more detailed answer.